# Spring-boot: load configuration file with @ImportResource error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a Rest service using Spring-boot but, deployed under Tomcat, it does not start because of some error in a configuration file loaded through `@ImportResource`.

The error is

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element "beans".
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_45]

My main class starts like this

```
@Configuration 
@ImportResource({"classpath:spring.xml"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages="mypackage")
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class, args);
    }
...
```

The file spring.xml starts like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mybatis="http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring"
    xsi:schemalocation=
            "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd   
            http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring
            http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring.xsd">
```

Any idea how to deal with it?

Comment: You should remove the whitespaces between your schema name and its definition. Put the following text in the same line and try again. "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"

Comment: @BrunoSilva : It's not that